# why can't i multiplicate two input fields with each other?

Tags: html, jquery

My multiplication is not working in my code, i get the output of zero in the console.
So i want to achieve multiplication through two input fields.
So the value in the 2 input fields gets multiplicated with each other on the button click.
This is my code:

```
<body>
<label for="">hoogte:</label>
<input type="text" id="hoogte">
<label for="">breedte:</label>
<input type="text" id="breedte">
<button id="btnKnop1">Klik Hier</button>
<div id="divResult"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        var hoogte = $('#hoogte').val();
        var breedte = $('#breedte').val();
        var result = hoogte *= breedte;
        $('#btnKnop1').on('click', function () {
            $('#divResult').val(result).html(result)
        })
    })

</script>
</body>
```

Hope i can get some help with this,
Thanks already!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Move the two `.val()` and the `*` lines *inside* the click handler - at the moment it's getting the values on load (which are empty) and calculating - when you click, presumably after you've changed the values, they're not updated so use the same values as on load (0*0).

Comment: You actually want `var result = hoogte * breedte;` - `*=` has a side effect of also changing `hoogte` - but it makes no difference to your code or the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const hoogte  = $('#hoogte');  // there is no interest to get a value
  const breedte = $('#breedte'); // at the document ready moment.

  $('#btnKnop1').on('click', function() {
    $('#divResult').html( Number( hoogte.val()) * Number(breedte.val()) );
  }) //.................. ^ change string to number
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="">hoogte:</label>
<input type="text" id="hoogte">

<label for="">breedte:</label>
<input type="text" id="breedte">

<button id="btnKnop1">Klik Hier</button>

<div id="divResult"></div>
```